# Кросбраузерный способ динамически добавлять атрибут onClick присваивая ему функцию с параметрами

Tags: html, javascript, dom

Как кроссбраузерно используя DOM можно добавить атрибут `onClick` и чтобы функция могла принимать параметры: например `obj.setAttribute("onclick","play(1);");` не работает, а IE если писать `obj.onclick=help;` (функция без параметров) то всё работает, а если `obj.onclick=play(2);` то функция `play(2);` начинает сама исполняться ещё до нажатия (очевидно как в случае с var i=func(3) присваиванием возвращённого значения) а как, имея ссылку на объект динамически кроссбраузерно добавить атрибут onClick с функцией с параметром, чтоб функция исполнялась только при нажатии?

Comment: Очень плохо знаю js, но вроде бы надо опускать аргументы у функции play. obj.onclick=play;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj.onclick = function(){ play(2); }
```

или

```
var help = function() { play(2); }
obj.onclick = help;
```

Comment: Спасибо единственное что нормально работает!

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать jQuery, то просто, у объекта ставите `id="someID"`, а дальше:

```
$("#someID").click( function () {
    play(2);
} );
```

Без jQuery:

```
function setEvent(c, name, action) {
    if (c.addEventListener) {
            c.addEventListener( name, action, false );
    }
    else if (c.attachEvent) {
            c.attachEvent("on" + name, action);
    }
    else {
            c["on" + name] = action;
    }
}
```

Соответственно использование:

```
setEvent(document.getElementById("someID"), "click", function () { play(2); } );
```

Comment: лучше использовать [jQuery.live("click", handler)](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: А я спрашиваю как без Jquery и с параметрами ведь в Jquery это же както реализовали?

Comment: А я не когда не слышал про addEventListener и в книге моей нет этого спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Без Jquery

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  $('someID').onclick = function()
    {
      //function
    }
}
```

Очень кроссбраузерно!

Comment: Тогда уж:

    document.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
            ...
        }
    }